# Microsoft Windows Store quit on start

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store

I'm on Windows 10. Suddenly Windows Store quit on start. The behavior is the same with [this video](https://youtu.be/Kp75hE4gAI0) uploaded by another guy. Running WSReset doesn' t help. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. I found the solution at the video comment:

Delete any files from `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8b bwe\LocalCache` would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A user on twitter asked Microsoft the following question on September 11th 2015.

> @windowsstore @Microsoft I can't open the windows app store in my 10
>   tablet, the app starts to open, then crashes, even after a reboot.

Microsoft replied with the following response:

> We are actively investigating this issue and should be back up and
>   running soon.

Additional Information:

> If you fire up the Windows Store on Windows 10 right now, you will
>   notice the app force closes within a few seconds while loading. You
>   are not alone. We’ve been receiving emails from tipsters informing us
>   of this issue (thanks Clarence and Markus!) and no word from Microsoft
>   as to why this is occurring.
>
> Let’s hope Microsoft resolves this issue before the start of the
>   weekend. Are you experiencing this issue too? Let us know in the
>   comments below. We’ll keep you posted as we learn more.
>
> Update: Microsoft has responded via Twitter saying they are looking
>   into the matter. The Windows Store app appears to be working again, at
>   least for me. How about you?

[Windows Store on Windows 10 currently force closing, no explanation why](http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-store-on-windows-10-currently-force-closing-no-explanation-why)